# Map for passed arguments isn't working as expected

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to properly tell typescript that each part of an enum expects different props.

Here's what I have:

```
function setDrawerContent <T>(data: DrawerData<T>) {
  //
}

// I would populate this as more content is needed in the future
enum DrawerContent {
  CONTENT_A,
  CONTENT_B,
}

// This is what I would call `setDrawerContent` with
interface DrawerData<T> {
  title: string;
  content: DrawerContent,
  props: T
}

// template for Content A
interface ContentAData {
  username: string;
}
// template for Content B
interface ContentBData {
  age: number;
}

// trying to map those interfaces above here
interface DrawerDataMap {
  [DrawerContent.CONTENT_A]: ContentAData,
  [DrawerContent.CONTENT_B]: ContentBData,
}

setDrawerContent<DrawerDataMap>({
  title: 'Title for Content A',
  content: DrawerContent.CONTENT_A,
  props: { username: 'some-class' } // error (but there shouldn't be): 'username' does not exist in type 'DrawerDataMap'
})
```

What am I doing wrong here? I would expect typescript to not complain above, just as I would expect it to complain below:

```
setDrawerContent<DrawerDataMap>({
  title: 'Title for Content A',
  content: DrawerContent.CONTENT_A,
  props: { age: 'some-class' } // `username` is supposed to be passed, not `age`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are giving `DrawerDataMap` as the generic parameter of the `setDrawerContent` function. The function then expects an argument with a `props` property of type `DrawerDataMap` (replace T with DrawerDataMap everywhere basically).

If you want props to be of type `ContentAData`, you can call the function like this :

```js
setDrawerContent<ContentAData>(...)
```

or even without specifying the type as it will automatically be inferred. But that is not what you want if I understood correctly, as you want `ContentAData` to be "linked" to `CONTENT_A` and same for `ContentBData` and `CONTENT_B`.

What you can do is create interfaces that represent the data to pass and create a union type, like so :

```js
interface ContentAData {
  title: string;
  content: DrawerContent.CONTENT_A,
  props: { username: string }
}

interface ContentBData {
  title: string;
  content: DrawerContent.CONTENT_B,
  props: { age: number }
}

type DrawerData = ContentAData | ContentBData;

function setDrawerContent(data: DrawerData) {
  //
}
```

Here is a REPL.it : https://replit.com/@billuc/UnionTypes#index.ts

I added a version with a base interface at the end, since it might be closer to what you need.